# Which box does the phrase "latter box" refer in the below two sentences?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-construction, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Which box does the phrase "latter box" refer in the below sentence ?

Sentence 1:
He ate oranges, in the box made from a box, and ate apples, in the latter box.

Sentence 2:
He ate oranges, in the box from which a box is made, and ate apples, in the latter box.

Pls help

Regards
Joe

Comment: He was in a box when he ate the fruit?

Comment: These sentences are very confusing.  They seem like something you might find in a logic puzzle.  Where did they come from?

Comment: The second clause in each example (*in a box made from a box* and *in a box from which a box is made*) are ungrammatical and should be removed.

Answer (score 0):

"the latter (something)" refers to the last mentioned of multiple things. For example,

> There is a man with a red shirt, and a man with a blue shirt. *The latter* also wears a hat.

means that the man with the blue shirt wears a hat, because he's mentioned last.

The opposite would be "the former":

> There is a man with a red shirt, and a man with a blue shirt. *The former* also wears a hat.

Here, the man with the red shirt wears a hat, because he's mentioned first.

In your example "the latter box" refers to the box that was mentioned last.

Comment: I’m pretty sure OP thinks [the nonsense 2nd clauses are key to his question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/291222/10446), and so answers probably shouldn’t gloss over them. He thinks he’s added “more boxes” to the mix (recursively?), and thus should have impacted the referent of “the latter”. Maybe best to explicitly call out the problematic clauses specifically in your answer.